# linking a variable in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, variables, sass

I need to set a variable in HTML and CSS.

[image]

As you can see I want to put a variable where the fixed values are so I only need to change once the value and it will set in both places

Comment: I don't think there is a way to share variables between HTML and CSS, as neither really have variables. You could set both from JS, though.

Comment: What you are looking at there is SCSS also known as sass, what is it you are trying to set

Answer (score 2):

CSS, SCSS is only used to change the appearance of your website / application, e.g. the color, font, positioning, size

If you need dynamic content - what changes when you do things, you need to implement javascript, either through an imported .js file or in a `<sctipt></script>` tag which you would normally put at the bottom of your body tag

In your javascript you will then need to create a function to say how you would like your content to change, and you would then need a way for your website / app to know when to change the content - usually done through an eventListener